# Lost in javascript comparisons

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison, element

I'm writing a script to be executed when my `body` element hasn't got any of the following classes:

> a OR b OR c AND d

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
if ((!$('body').hasClass('a')) || (!$('body').hasClass('b')) || ((!($('body').hasClass('c')) && (!$('body').hasClass('d'))))) {

}
```

**UPDATE**

This seems to work:

```
if (!($('body').hasClass('a') || $('body').hasClass('b') || $('body').hasClass('c') && $('body').hasClass('d'))) {

}
```

Comment: immediate aid came to my mind : try writing your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ //here }); not sure if it's the case. Share your code through jsFiddle. look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/3yo670b1/ , your code is working fine here.

Comment: It doesn't really work, look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/cmx3fa3z/

Comment: You said your code will execute when any of the classes a,b,c,d isn't present. So try this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/p5e67dw0/

Comment: So, this seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/kx9t971u/

Comment: @OBD you need to study up on operators before continuing because you seem to be throwing spaghetti at the wall and see what sticks. Go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators

Comment: @sometingthere you are right of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```js
$(function(){
   if ((!$('body').hasClass('a')) || (!$('body').hasClass('b')) || !($('body').hasClass('c') && $('body').hasClass('d'))) {

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a body that doesnt have any of the classes, so you need to use `&&`. Heres what happens:

`if(hasclass(a) || hasclass(b))` = `if(true OR false)` = `if(true)`

Above the OR operator `||` means that once it hits a true evaluation, it will execute your `if`-block.

`if(hasclass(a) && hasclass(b))` = `if(true AND false)` = `if(false)`

Here the AND operator `&&` means that once you hit a `false` evaluation, you block won't be executed.

You want the last thing to happen, since you want it to have neither of the classes. Learn how to play with these operators as they can be very confusing. As long as you remember that the AND operator will execute only if all statements are true and the OR operator will only execute if one of the statements is true. Nested operators work the same, so `if((a = b && b = c) || (a = c))` will execute if a,b and c are the same OR when a and c are the same, but not when a and b are the same or a and c are the same.

More on expression and operators (specifically Bitwise and a must read): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators

Comment: Alas Í can't even get the OR comparison to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/orjan/swhdfdox/

Comment: @OBD Again, this is because you want _no classes to be found_ so you need the AND operator. OR is if you want one of them to be true at least, which - in your fiddle - is the case as the b class is applied. Your fiddle says `if(NOT hasClass(a) OR NOT hasClass(b))` which is evaluated to `if(true OR false)` which, in turn, returns true because one is true. With the AND it becomes `if(NOT hasClass(a) AND NOT hasClass(b))` which is evaluated to `if(true AND false)` which means not all statements are true and the block gets skipped.